# OnRangeSelectedListener and ClickListener both are not working in Material-calendarview

Tags: android, material-design, calendarview

I'm using latest version of material calendarview with range mode and when I'm trying to get selected dates, listeners are not working.

I'm using them as:

```
@Override
public void onRangeSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull List<CalendarDay> dates) {
startDateTextView.setText(FORMATTER.format(widget.getSelectedDates().get(0).getDate()) + "");
endDateTextView.setText(FORMATTER.format(widget.getSelectedDates().get(widget.getSelectedDates().size() - 1).getDate()) + "");
}

@OnClick(R.id.calendarView)
public void getAndSetDates(View view) {
if (endDateFlag) {
    endDateTextView.setText(FORMATTER.format(calendarView.getSelectedDates().get(calendarView.getSelectedDates().size() - 1).getDate()));
} else {
    startDateTextView.setText(FORMATTER.format(calendarView.getSelectedDates().get(0).getDate()));
}
}
```

I tried to debug and found they're not getting called. Btw, I'm using https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview